# Method not found: 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Pipelines.GetRenderEngineFactory.GetRenderEngineFactoryArgs.get_RenderEngineType()

Tags: jss, layout-service

I am working on Sitecore JSS and created a sample application. When I am trying access with the new hostname, configured in the app patch file, I got below error.

```
35472 12:00:27 ERROR Failed to render rendering
Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'System.String Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Pipelines.GetRenderEngineFactory.GetRenderEngineFactoryArgs.get_RenderEngineType()'.
Source: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.Pipelines.GetRenderEngineFactory.GetHttpEngineFactory.Process(GetRenderEngineFactoryArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Pipelines.GetRenderEngineFactory.GetRenderEngineFactoryPipeline.GetFactory(GetRenderEngineFactoryArgs args)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.ResolveRenderEngine()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

Method name prefixed with "`get_`" is something not common. I decompiled the dll `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine` and `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http` and I do find where it is being called but not found the implementation of this method. Not sure, from where this method request is coming from.

Any clue?

Comment: When you see `get_RenderEngineType`, it means that `RenderEngineType { get { ... } }` property is called

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i even didn't find the said method in class GetRenderEngineFactoryArgs and even in base class PipelineArgs.

Comment: Can you share the app config?

Comment: Its a default app config what we are getting from nuget package for jss react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an inconsistent JSS installation. Ensure all `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices` assemblies are of the same version. If you are referencing JSS assemblies via NuGet, ensure you are referencing the correct version and not deploying the wrong version into your solution.